# How to group objects in a list by two fields?

Tags: kotlin, collections, grouping

I would like to group a list of objects basing on two fields in those objects.

Let's say I have an object like this:

```
data class ItemDataDTO(
    val itemId: BigInteger?,
    val sequence: BigInteger?,
    val serialNumber: String?,
    val pickingId: String?,
    val runId: String? = null,
    val warehouse: String?,
)
```

Now I have a list of `ItemDataDTO` containing a lot of items. I would like to group them by `runId` and `pickingId` (because I need those items that have the same `pickingId` and `runId` grouped somehow.)

```
val items: List<ItemDataDTO> = someItemRepository.getItemsForWarehouse("someWarehouseId")
val groupedItems = items.groupBy({ it.runId }, { it.pickingId })
```

This doesn't work. I found out that I could use `groupingBy()` function along with a `Triple`, but I want just them to be grouped by two values...

```
val groupedItems = items.groupingBy { Triple(it.runId, it.pickingId, null) }
```

But this doesn't work as well. I tried to add a third parameter instead of `null`, using `it.warehouse`:

```
val groupedItems = items.groupingBy { Triple(it.runId, it.pickingId, it.warehouse) }
```

It returns an instance of `Grouping<ItemDataDTO, Triple<String?, String?, String?>>` and I'm not sure what to do with this object.

What could I do to properly group those objects?

In a perfect world, I would like to transform this list to a list of something like:

```
data class PickingList(
    val runId: String,
    val pickingId: String,
    val items: List<ItemDataDTO>,
)
```

So the output would be a `List<PickingList>`.

Answer (score 4):

There's nothing special about it really! `groupBy` takes a `keySelector` function which returns *some value* to be used as a key for that item. So if you want to match on two properties, that key item needs to be composed of those two values.

A `Triple` with two items is a `Pair`, so you can just do this:

```
// just FYI, "it.runId to it.pickingId" is shorthand for a Pair - you see it more
// when defining key/value pairs for maps though. "Pair(x, y)" might read better here
// since you're really just combining values, not describing how one relates to the other
items.groupBy { Pair(it.runId, it.pickingId) }
```

So each item will produce a `Pair` with those two values. Any other items with a  `Pair` that matches (as far as the `equals` function goes) will be put into the same group. It's a bit like adding to a `Map`, except that if a key already exists, the value is added to a list instead of overwriting the previous value.

You can do that with any key really. `Pair` and `Triple` are just quick, general convenience classes for bundling a few items together - but a lot of the time it's better to define your own data structure, e.g. using a `data class`. So long as two instances with the same data are *equal*, they count as the same key for grouping.

---

As for the output you want, with the `PickingList`... you *could* use something like that for your grouping operation - but in that case you'd have to pretty much reimplement `groupBy` yourself. You'd have to take an item, and work out its composite key from the properties you want to consider. Then you'd need to find a match for that key in some store you've created for your groups

If it's a list of `PickingList`s, you'd need to go through each one, comparing its IDs to the ones you want, adding to its list if you find a match and creating the object if you can't find it.

If you're storing a map of `Pair(id1, id2) -> PickingList` then that's close to how `groupBy` works anyway, in terms of generating a key for lookups. In that case, you might want to just use `groupBy` to group all your items, and then transform the final map:

```
items.groupBy { Pair(it.runId, it.pickingId) }
    .map { (ids, list) ->
        PairingList(runId = ids.first, pickingId = ids.second, items = list)
    }
```

This takes every map entry (a `Pair` of IDs and the list of all things grouped by those IDs) and uses it to create a `PairingList` from that key/value data. Basically, once you've grouped all your data, you transform it into the data structures you want to work with.

---

This is also a good example of why your own data class might be better than just using a `Pair` - `it.first` doesn't really tell you what that value *is* in the `Pair`, just that it's the first of the two values. Whereas

```
data class IdCombo(val runId: String, val pickingId: String)
```

works the same as a `Pair`, but the properties have useful names and make your code much more readable and less prone to bugs:

```
map { (ids, list) ->
        // didn't even bother with the named arguments, since the names are in
        // the ids object now!
        PairingList(ids.runId, ids.pickingId, items = list)
    }
```